# GitHub webhooks - how to detect fact of merge?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, webhooks

I am developing an app that would detect that something was merged in specific branch and take some actions based on that.
In order to solve my problem I need to find the name of a branch that was merged to the branch I monitor.

Let's say GitHub sends me "everything" and my script must react when "some-branch" is merged to branch "Tests". Also my script must be able to detect the name of merged branch (in this case "some-branch").

Only solution I found so far - is to read property "message" of every commit in array "commits" and parse it. They are pretty tipical: "Merge branch 'some-branch' into Tests".

There are two problems

- Message theoretically could be modified by user (for example SourceTree shows you editor after conflict resolve)
- In case of Fast-Forward there is no message

What could you advise, how can I detect fact of merge and the name of merged branch better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid due to the protocol of git, this is not always possible.

1. In fast-forward case, no new blobs are created, but only blobs are transferred to github.
2. If a merge commit exists, as you already realized, the commit message may be overridden by user.

I guess the best we can do is to monitor a branch, and consider in terms of *push* instead of *merge*.

Answer (score 3):

Only if the branch merge is via pull request on github, then you can detect the event or relate things, such as **pull_request_review** event.

And for the command to view branches merged into `Tests` branch  is `git branch --merged Tests`.